# Access fact of a system from another

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to access facts of one system from another system via any built-in puppet command? I tried to do that with puppet facts find "node_certificate" but its not working (instead I get facts of the same system on which I'm running the command).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tags](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_tags.html) and [exported resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_exported.html).

This will create an exported resource and tag it. For example the template used for the file can contain facts variables.
This is nagios example - you probably want this on every host.

```
@@file { "${::fqdn}.conf":
  ensure  => file,
  mode    => '0640',
  mode    => root,
  group   => root,
  path    => "/etc/nagios/hosts/${::fqdn}.conf",
  content => template('nagios/host.conf.erb'),
  tag     => "nagios-hosts",
}
```

and this will collect them. You want this only on nagios server.

```
  File <<| tag == 'nagios-hosts' |>>
```